# javascript formData.entries() is empty but input and it's name is defined. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I am changing image it firing event of form submit. I want to post image by using ajax and as you can see I am extracting form values by using formData. But I am unable to retrieve the form data nothing is printed when I am looping though formData entries.

```js
$('.image-input-desktop').on('change', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#image_upload_desktop').trigger('submit');
})

$('#image_upload_desktop').on('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Form submitted');
    let formData = new FormData(this);
    for (var [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(key, value);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="image_upload_desktop" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="image" class="image-input-desktop">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that it uses [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this), therefore the `this` parameter that you pass to `FormData` is actually the `window`.

You can get a reference to the `form` element through the `event.target`

```js
$('.image-input-desktop').on('change', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#image_upload_desktop').trigger('submit');
})

$('#image_upload_desktop').on('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this === window);
  console.log('Form submitted');
  debugger;
  let formData = new FormData(event.target);
  for (var [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(key, value);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="image_upload_desktop" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image" class="image-input-desktop">
</form>
```